# How do I "cut out" an icon with a background in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, cs5

I am having some difficulties trying to delete the space where I created a simple '+' icon.
Here are some images for reference.

[image: What I am starting with...]

[image: The icon cut out and is vector in the middle...]

I hope this explains what I am trying to accomplish. Sorry for not using technical terms, I do not know them!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the software package. The generic term(s) for using one shape to alter another one in this manner are: "intersection" "subtraction," "union/merge," and "XOR (eXclusive OR)".

You can search the documentation for your software for terms that look like these. Often they are under an "object" menu and in adobe products, they are on a palette which may be accessed via the "window" menu ("Pathfinder").

Answer (score 1):

Select both shapes and click the **Minus Front** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

But Horatio is correct, looking in the help files for "subtract shape" will result in steps to do what you want. [Help Results](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6462a.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could also select both and make it a **compound path**.

1. Select both with smaller form on top
2. Object -> Compound Path -> Make

*Shortcut*: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

In Photoshop you have to select the shape you wanted to delete some of the area. Make sure the **Direct Selection Tool** is active. Then create the shape you wanted to intersect on the shape, then select **subtract** from path operations as for your question.

There are other options like:
Combine, Subtract, Intersect and Exclude

Comment: The question was not about Photoshop.